# Invalid cast exception: trying to join two tables using linq-sql

Tags: c#, linq, join

I'm trying to join two tables using their common id which is MOTHERID. But he code below was working fine but at some point it starts  throwing "Invalid cast exception" at:

```
 var firstQuery = (from s in _maternalvisitvaluedb.Value select s).ToList();
```

I think the exception is being caused by the toList() conversion because when I remove .ToList() it works fine but I need to use that for the rest of the code to work properly. Here is some part of the code:

```
MaternalVisitData _maternalvisitvaluedb =
new  MaternalVisitData(MaternalVisitData.strConnectionString);
MaternalCareData _maternalcarevaluedb = 
new MaternalCareData(MaternalCareData.strConnectionString);

var firstQuery = (from s in _maternalvisitvaluedb.Value select s).ToList();
var secondQuery = (from t in _maternalcarevaluedb.Value select t).ToList();

var result = (from s in firstQuery
join k in secondQuery
on s.MotherId equals k.MotherId
where (DateTime)s.SecondVisit.Date == DateTime.Now.Date 
select s).ToList();
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try specific type alternate of var in below lines :

```
var firstQuery = (from s in _maternalvisitvaluedb.Value select s).ToList();
var secondQuery = (from t in _maternalcarevaluedb.Value select t).ToList();
```

like this :

```
List<maternalvisitvaluedb> firstQuery = (list<maternalvisitvaluedb>)(from s in _maternalvisitvaluedb.Value select s).ToList();
List<maternalcarevaluedb> secondQuery = (List<maternalcarevaluedb>)(from t in _maternalcarevaluedb.Value select t).ToList();
```

it's a pseudo , I hope it helps you

Comment: I have tried it and the data contexts maternalvisitvaluedb and maternalcarevaluedb doesn't consider them as valid datatypes.

Comment: i knew they are not valid datatypes,please change them to their valid datatype that you are using

Comment: I have changed to its valid datatype still it is throwing the invalid cast exception.

Comment: 1.does these tables have relations?if they are,check them to doesn't be null. 2.Is motherid a primary key?if it's not check it to doesn't be null.